# Java Generics - Cannot convert from <? extends MyObject> to <MyObject>

Tags: java, generics

Why does the following code give a compile error?

```
public MyObject(Builder<? extends MyObject> builder) {
    // Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyObject.Builder<capture#5-of ? extends MyObject> to MyObject.Builder<MyObject>
    Builder<MyObject> myObjBuilder = builder;
}
```

If the Builder type is a subclass of MyObject, then why can't you assign builder to just type MyObject? I need to do this because I am unable to use an object of type MyObject with the builder. Take a look at this code for example:

```
public MyObject(Builder<? extends MyObject> builder) {
    // The method getData(capture#8-of ? extends MyObject) in the type Builder<capture#8-of ? extends MyObject> is not applicable for the arguments (MyObject)
    this.data = builder.getData(this);
}
```

I feel like this should be allowed. Or am I missing something here? Is there a way to do this without casting builder to `(Builder<MyObject>)` and having to use @SuppressWarnings ?

Also note that I need Builder to be `<? extends MyObject>` because the MyObject and its Builder will be subclassed (as it is abstract).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AlexisKing, I don't think this question matches that one, but I do think it needs the same answer as [What are the risks of explicitly casting from a list of type List<? extends MyObject> to a list of type List<MyObject> in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403293/what-are-the-risks-of-explicitly-casting-from-a-list-of-type-list-extends-myob)

Comment: See also [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/465378)

Comment: I guess I wasn't using the right search keywords. I looks for a while. thanks for the link

Comment: Because generics are invariant, read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Foo<? extends Bar>` is not a `Foo<Bar>`.

Say `Foo` has a method:

```
void add (T t)
```

then by contract, you can only add `T` objects. Now if `T` is instantiated as `? extends Bar`, we don't know the type. Accepting `Bar` could lead to problematic behavior: if you have an `ArrayList<Foo>` you expect the `ArrayList` to contain only `Foo` instances. If you would see the `ArrayList<Foo>` as a `ArrayList<SuperFoo>`, one can't guarantee that the `ArrayList<Foo>` contains only `Foo`'s.

Some languages enable [*covariance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29): if you only use `T` as output, you can say that a class `Foo<T>` is a the same as `Foo<SuperT>` as well (the same with input). But currently Java doesn't support that. C# however does on the interface level.

Comment: But a method `add(Object)` actually *does* accept any subclass of `Object`, isn't it?

Comment: @MCEmperor: a subclass yes. But here you want to "superclass" it. Thus you want to convert a `ArrayList<Integer>` to `ArrayList<Object>`. That would imply that `add(Integer)` would accept an `Object`. Evidently that's not possible.

Comment: I read up on covariance and invariance, and this all makes sense to me now. With my case however, I know that a cast to Builder of type MyObject will be type safe at runtime, so I guess It will be ok to do so even though it is ugly. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @User12345: sure, you can do an explicit type cast, but if you add items at runtime to the `ArrayList`, you probably will get an error, so only use it when it is absolutely necessary.